# How can I practice Climbing without the actual wall and/or equipment?

Tags: gear, rock-climbing, bouldering, exercises

I had never been a gifted kind of a climber being more fascinated by Backpacking than Rock Climbing. Its been almost 2 years that I did some genuine climbing. And, I am planning to resume it very soon. But, Instead of gambling with any actual climbing place I intend to get in touch with it, and do some basic sets of exercise so that I can get back to where I was. Over this long break, I have had a major lower back injury around 8 months back and a Toe injury(which made me limp for about 2 weeks) couple of months ago during trekking.
So I want to ask for any sort of drills with which I can determine what I need to practice more so that I can get into climbing. Due to work place issue, I am going to be away from the Wall and the equipment for about a month from now. But if I can work out on something during this span in order to get into the position where I can resume, would be glad to know!

Comment: a similar question was asked on the fitness.stackexchange site.  Does this speak to your questions:  http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11416/home-exercises-for-training-for-indoor-rock-climbing

Comment: basically, you can't work on technique without an actual wall.  But you can work on fitness and some climbing specific strength.

Comment: By balance, do you mean balance and efficient movement while rock climbing?  I've never tried to do it away from a climbing wall.  I'm not sure how much transfer there would be.  You could try doing yoga poses (er, you're from India.  I mean the Americanized, non-religious isometric balance pose based version of yoga that American yuppies have adopted, not necessarily real "yoga" :) ).  If you're recovering from foot and back injuries, though, I'd make sure to take it easy and not reinjure yourself.

Comment: http://www.rei.com/product/478026/power-putty-hand-strengthener  Is this what you mean by hand putty?  Yeah, that stuff is pretty good.  I used to use it as a warmup before climbing.  You can use it for a while, with the right level of strength its pretty easy on the joints, and its a fine way to add some endurance to your grip.  They're not ALL that strenuous, however.  Even the hardest isn't all that hard for a strong climber.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best practice for climbing is to actually go climbing. I have wasted both time and money experimenting with training setups at home for practicing climbing, and I have mostly been disappointed. Since then I have transitioned my efforts at home to **staying in shape for climbing** (slightly different from what you are asking.) Unless you want to spend thousands of dollars, have a lot of spare time and are very dedicated to replicate something that is not really replicable, I would suggest (like DavidR mentioned in his comment,) you work on general fitness (with a focus on strengthening fingers and core), and possibly loose those few extra pounds that you are not that proud of anyways.

The accepted answer for [the question that DavidR linked to](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11416/home-exercises-for-training-for-indoor-rock-climbing) does a pretty good job answering the strengthening part.

Since you mentioned balance, I thought I'dd suggest picking up [slacklining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slacklining). I am not sure how much it helps you on the wall, but it is a fun activity and I am fairly certain that it has helped me on some pretty treacherous approaches to climbs (as far as I can recall I haven't actually fallen on bad terrain since I picked up slacklining.)